# Angular JS conditional logic to check "class name" exists

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Below Angular JS code works fine on Mouseover & Mouseout. Need help regard adding conditional logic on JS code.

If class name "active" exists, img src path have to be in "overImg" even if user mouseover & mouseout. But, present behaviour removes overImg once user mouseout from element. Active state have to be different from the rest of navigation element.

**AngularJS:**

```
.directive('eleHoverAction', function() {
return {
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        var imgObj = $(elem).find('img');
        var upImg = attrs.eleUpImgSrc;
        var overImg = attrs.eleOverImgSrc;

        elem.bind('mouseover', function () {
            $(imgObj).attr("src", overImg);
            scope.$apply();
        });
        elem.bind('mouseout', function() {
            $(imgObj).attr("src", upImg);
            scope.$apply();
        });
    }
  };                
});
```

**HTML:**

```
 <li class="menu-item menu-item--category active" ele-hover-action ele-up-img-src="images/test1.png" ele-over-img-src="images/test1-over.png">
   <a href="#"><img src="images/test1.png" oversrc="images/test1-over.png"  alt=""/><span>Test1</span></a>
</li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item--category" ele-hover-action ele-up-img-src="images/test2.png" ele-over-img-src="images/test2-over.png">
  <a href="#"><img src="images/test2.png" oversrc="images/test2-over.png"  alt=""/><span>Test2</span></a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most obvious method is to add an `if` statement to your "mouseout" handler that checks if the element `hasClass` active:

```
.directive('eleHoverAction', function() {
return {
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        var imgObj = elem.find('img');
        var upImg = attrs.eleUpImgSrc;
        var overImg = attrs.eleOverImgSrc;

        elem.bind('mouseover', function () {
            imgObj.attr("src", overImg);
            scope.$apply();
        });
        elem.bind('mouseout', function() {
            if (!elem.hasClass("active")) {
                imgObj.attr("src", upImg);
            }
            scope.$apply();
        });

        if (elem.hasClass("active")) {
            imgObj.attr("src", overImg);
        } else {
            imgObj.attr("src", upImg);
        }
    }
  };                
});
```

I went ahead and set the `src` attribute of the image based on the directive attributes. You could just take that part out if you don't want it. Also, wrapping `elem` in a jQuery call is redundant because Angular elements are already wrapped in either jQuery (if available when Angular loads) or its own jQLite. Otherwise, you wouldn't be able to call `elem.bind`.

[Try it in a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/wx7nhetk/)

Comment: In my code I had to wrap the element like so `angular.element(element).hasClass(active)`